# Filesystem changes inside Docker container aren't displayed onto the host filesystem

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the Docker and docker-compose to run my app inside a container. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    omsevents:
        build:
            context: ./omsevents
        volumes:
            - "../oms-events:/usr/app/oms-events"
            - "../oms-events/assets:/usr/app/oms-events/assets"
```

The thing is, my app is a server and one of the things it does is file upload. When I upload a file it is created inside a container (I can `bash` inside the container and check and it's there, in `/usr/app/oms-events/assets`), bit it's not created on the host filesystem (the `../oms-events/assets/` folder is empty).

What can be the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but does it work with the explicit `"`? The manual says differently, but I don't know if it matters ( https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ )

Comment: Try providing absolute path for directory on host filesystem.

Comment: @yuva I tried to specify absolute path to the host filesystem's folder, but it worked the same way

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volumedriver) of Docker Compose:

> You can mount a relative path on the host, which will expand relative to the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative paths should always begin with . or ..

So you can try moving the docker-compose file into the context directory and remove the context clause from the build section, leaving it just `build: .` (or wherever your Dokerfile is). Then just fix the relative paths of the volumes or try with absolute ones.

Comment: I can't check your link as it is broken, but I'm not really sure if it is true? I'm using this  - .:/usr/src/app , and the dot works perfectly for me

Comment: @Nanne Sorry, just fixed it ;)

Comment: I tried replacing my relative paths with absolute ones, still no luck

Comment: @Serge1peshcoff Can you test with moving the docker-compose file into the context directory and remove the `context` clause from it and leave just `build: .`?